# Can Haystack filter by a geodjango PointField?

Tags: python, django, full-text-search, geodjango, django-haystack

I want to be able to use django-haystack to do full text searches on a model.  This model uses a PointField to store coordinates.  I want to filter the results of a search based on the distance from a point.  Is this possible with Haystack?  Is there a better way to do this?

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class Listing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    location = models.PointField()
```

Comment: UPDATE: As of Haystack 2.0, spatial search has been implimented, and works very well with geodjango fields.

Comment: Hi @Agabel. Could you post any code samples that helped solve your problem with Haystack 2.0 and geodjango? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want users to input geographic information, like an address or zipcode into the text search. This is how I did it, though I'm not sure how it scales yet. I just finished this 5 minutes ago.

[You should create a custom search form](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/views_and_forms.html#ref-views-and-forms) subclassed from SearchForm or one of the other options (for me it was FacetedSearchForm). Overwrite the search method.

First turn the search string into a point. http://code.google.com/p/geopy/wiki/GettingStarted

```
class MainSearchForm(FacetedSearchForm):

    def search(self):

        query = self.cleaned_data['q']
        g = geocoders.Google()
        place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode('%s' % query)
        pnt = fromstr('POINT(%s %s)' % (lng, lat), srid=4326)
```

Then take the search query set, I used [RelatedSearchQuerySet](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/searchqueryset_api.html?highlight=relatedsearchqueryset#relatedsearchqueryset) since it allows you to use load_all_queryset() which is where I filtered by distance. It's GeoDjango to the rescue with [GeoDjango Distance Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries). With the distance query, you can choose how to filter with distance less than, greater than etc. And the distance itself, in whatever units you want.

```
        sqs = RelatedSearchQuerySet().load_all()
        sqs = sqs.load_all_queryset(Listing, 
                                    Listing.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(pnt, D(mi=20))))
        return sqs
```

That should be a solid start. Hope this points you in the right direction.